# Securing/Escaping Output of file content - reading via fread() in PHP

Tags: plugin-development, security, escaping

I am working on securing the content read from a file via the `fread()` function.

```
private function readfile_chunked($file) {
    $chunksize = 1024 * 1024;

    // Open Resume
    $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');

    if (false === $handle) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    while (!@feof($handle)) {
        $content  = @fread($handle, $chunksize);
        echo wp_kses_post( $content);

        if (ob_get_length()) {
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }

    return @fclose($handle);
}
```

The aforementioned `wp_kses_post($content)` is suggested by the WP plugin review team to secure the file content as well. But this solution is not working for me. It is downloading the file in an infinite loop. Any help will be appreciated on "How we can escape output of `fread()` in WordPress?". Or any alternative function so we can skip the "echo" function.

Comment: FYI: The function is just called [`fread()`](https://www.php.net/fread). The `@` has another meaning (see [this answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653360)).

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading the file in a loop"?

Comment: Also, what is in this file? Where is it being output?

Comment: I don't believe `wp_kses_post` can be used this way on partial chunks of the file, you'll need to collect the entire files contents into a single variable _then_ use `wp_kses_post` or it'll see partial tags and incomplete markup in each chunk. Also `@` is very bad practice and should be avoided at all costs

Comment: @kero, the download completes and starts downloading again.

Comment: Please confirm whether we should sanitize the file content or not? Because neither sanitizes function of WordPress is working for me. Can anyone please suggest the alternative solution according to WP standards or correct my above code approch?